# Spring bean initialization with autowired simpMessagingTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean, spring-kafka

I'm building a Spring MVC project which, at certain point should be able to read from a Kafka topic and send consumed data to some frontend. To achieve that, I'm using:

- Spring KafkaTemplate, in order to consume messages from Kafka Server.
- SimpMessagingTemplate, to send each consumed message to frontend, via Spring Websockets.

This is what I have:

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "metrics");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaReceiver receiver() {
        return new KafkaReceiver();
    }

}
```

**KafkaReceiver.java**

```
public class KafkaReceiver {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "metrics")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        MetricRecord m = new MetricRecord(new Long(record.offset()), record.key().toString(), record.value().toString());
        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/metrics/records", m.toString());
    }
}
```

I also have WebSocketConfig in place. At this moment, it is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/metrics");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/metricsApp");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/kafka-metrics-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

This is my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.11.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.3.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-annotations:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.1.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jruby.jcodings:jcodings:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jruby.joni:joni:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6:system
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.16.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-core:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-streaming:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-distcp:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-daemon:commons-daemon:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-hive:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.ibm.jbatch:com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-hbase:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-pig:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-batch:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
```

When running this project I get the following error (full log):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.isStereotypeWithNameValue(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.doRegisterBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:210)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1439)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:78)
2017-10-02 16:25:35.967:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6b695b06{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8082}
2017-10-02 16:25:35.970:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @7601ms
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is really more stack trace to determine the root of cause.
On the other hand you have mentioned Spring Websockets, but we really don't see any declaration for that. Something like `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`?

**UPDATE**

You have a mix of versions:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.3.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.11.RELEASE:compile
```

Consider to use everything from `org.springframework` in the version `5.0`.

Comment: Hi Artem! Post updated with my websocket config class

Comment: OK! But where is full stack trace for the error? You know, we don't play here spy games. Please, be more specific. Also, please, share the versions combination: spring and spring-kafka.

Comment: details added. Anything else just tell. I do really want this to work :D

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: That solved, Artem! Thank you so much! It now starts server properly, but has some problem in WebSocketConfig perhaps. It says "VM130:2 GET http://localhost:9999/kafka-metrics-websocket/info?t=1506963144665 404 (Not Found)". I'm pushing the luck, I know. And I'm sorry

Comment: Yeah... It's again different story. You should be sure that you start your app at the empty context root, since your URL for endpoint is without that. Plus be sure that your app is really on that `9999` port